# Implementing SAML along-side traditional authentication

Tags: php, authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I'm having difficulty finding guidance on the implementation of SAML alongside an existing, traditional authentication system.

I have created a SaaS application in CodeIgnitor which has the typical, run-of-the-mill authentication system using a local users table with hashing and salting etc.

I'm looking to add SAML SSO to attract more enterprise customers. I have a question however where my Google Fu is falling short.

How can I integrate SAML authentication so that it works along-side my traditional, local authentication? If my customers choose SAML then I will require them to bind their existing local accounts to their SAML federated identities. What do I do to cater for my non-SAML users?

Do I need two login URL's such as https://app.com/saml/login for my SAML users and https://app.com/login for my non-SAML users, and just expect customers to choose the right one? Or perhaps I ask for their email/username first, and then require them to submit that value to see if they're SAML or not - and route them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an Identity provider (IDP) that supports SAML.

You use the IDP Initiated SAML profile.

Your app. is connected to the IDP via a SAML stack.

Other enterprises can then federate with your IDP i.e. login to your web site with their credentials via SAML.

The IDP Initiated SAML profile provides a URL that you give to customers that takes them to your IDP with their customer credentials and thence to your app.

Users going direct to your website use the local connection.

That said, rather use OpenID Connect - it's much simpler but the principles are the same.